# Socket.IO with Express will not connect using https (Apache2 Ubuntu16.04)

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I am not very experienced with SSL certs and Im hopping someone can help me find out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to host a NodeJS application with it's own port (*:1729) with Apache2 which has SSL enabled on port 443 (from which it servers a client application and not the NodeJS/Express/Socket.io application in question). When I set up Express with http it works fine, my client application communicates without error to the NodeJS application, however when I use https with express such as this:

```
this.express = require('express');  
this.app = this.express();

var https = require('https');  
var fs = require('fs');

var sslPath = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.example.com/';

var options = {  
    key: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(sslPath + 'fullchain.pem')
};

this.server = https.createServer(options, this.app);  
this.io = require('socket.io').listen(this.server);  
this.server.listen(1729);
```

When ever my client app tries to connect I get this error:

[image]

``` node: ../src/util-inl.h:196: TypeName* node::Unwrap(v8::Local<v8::Object>) [with TypeName = node::TLSWrap]: Assertion ``(object->InternalFieldCount()) > (0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped) ```

Any advice or corrections that could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you using? `node --version`

Comment: I am using node v4.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you of the help! :) Updating my NodeJS to the latest version made the error disappear and the application is communicating with the client with no error's as well.

[node: Github issue # 3682](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3682)

I just followed these steps.

[AskUbuntu: How can I update my nodeJS to the latest version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)